# Cite page number in parentheses

Tags: bibtex, citing

When I use `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and type `Hello~\cite[Fig.~6]{wickerson15}.`, I get something like this:

> Hello [1, Fig. 6].

I don't like the comma separator here, and would rather have my `\cite` command produce

> Hello [1 (Fig. 6)].

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you could load it with the option `notesep={}` and then write `\cite[(Fig.~6)]{wickerson15}`. Not very elegant, but quite simple...

Comment: Adding to Mico's comment, you can then redefine `\cite`: `\let\oldcite\cite \newcommand{\newcite}[2][]{\oldcite[(#1)]{#2}} \let\cite=\newcite`. But I'm not sure whether redefining `\cite` this way is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

It's very easy. `;-)`

The macro responsible for the final printing of the citation is `\@cite`, the standard definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 6271:
\def\@cite#1#2{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}
```

The `\if@tempswa` conditional is set to true if `\cite` has an optional argument.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor2015,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={A paper},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2015},
 pages={1-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cite[2]{[{#1\if@tempswa\ (#2)\fi}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Citation~\cite[p.~3]{uthor2015}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A possible solution with `natbib` (when numeric references are used) is as follows.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor2015,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={A paper},
 journal={Journal},
 year={2015},
 pages={1-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\NAT@cmt#1\fi{ (#1)\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Citation~\cite[p.~3]{uthor2015}.

Citation~\cite[Pre][post]{uthor2015}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I later realised that I *was* using the `natbib` package after all; it was being loaded by my document class. This meant that egreg's solution did not work for me - perhaps `natbib` does not use the `\@cite` command that egreg redefined? However, the following, which is obtained by combining Mico and Timm's comments

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={\ }}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{%
\ifx\\#1\\%
  \oldcite{#2}%
\else%
  \oldcite[(#1)]{#2}%
\fi}
```

works nicely. Thanks all.

**Edit.** Now that I'm using `biblatex`, the following seems to work for me:

```
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\space}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand\cite[2][]{%
\ifx\\#1\\%
  \oldcite{#2}%
\else%
  \oldcite[(#1)]{#2}%
\fi}
```

Comment: I had inferred you weren't using `natbib` from `\bibliographystyle{plain}` that makes no sense with the package. Your workaround breaks the usage of \cite`, not allowing the *two* optional arguments. I added a proper solution to my answer.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Using `plain` wasn't giving me any problems, but I understand now that I should have been using `plainnat` or `abbrvnat`.